# C printf: insert line above printed text

Tags: c, printf, ansi-escape

I want to print with printf above printed lines WITHOUT overwriting old ones. The code below prints

```
0
1
Hallo
A0
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

I want the output to be

```
0
1
Hallo
A0
A1
A2
A3
A4
2
3
4
```

Is there a possibilty to do this with escape codes (like line up)?

```
#include "stdio.h" 

#define ANSI_LINE_UP                "\033[3A"


int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    printf(ANSI_LINE_UP "Hallo\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("A%d\n", i);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I use Kubuntu 18.04, if this is relevant.

To make it a bit clearer what I want:

I want to have the output of some printf at the end, so it looks like this:

printf(...)
   printf(...)

specialprintf(,,,)
   specialprintf(,,,)

Note: The order of all prints might be different while execution. I just need the normal ones first, then the special ones. If the special ones are in a different order, it is still fine.

This is part of an embedded project. @Arkku solution is good, but I don't quite get it working as I want.

Comment: let me know my edit is proper one.

Comment: Do you have a real case or just curious? Your example does not make much sence because it could be easily done by modifying order of `printf`s, and escape codes are generally neither portable nor easy to use.

Comment: The most portable way would be to use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Comment: This is just a simple example. I want to do something more complex but it should do the same.

Comment: It must work using printf as this should also work while printing text via UART from a micro controller. I can't use ncurses there.

Comment: I had hoped that ANSI insert line ("\033[3L") would do the trick, but I tried it and it doesn't work (at least not on macOS using the Terminal app)

Comment: In light of additional comments, it seems that the real question is entirely different from this. I suggest asking another question with the actual problem, since multithreaded access to a single terminal is definitely not the question you asked here.

Comment: The multi threading is no issue, everything is protected by semaphores. I just have to figure out how many lines I have to move around. I think @Arkku has solved it, I will mark it as solution when I solved my last few problems. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously this depends on what your terminal supports, but in case it supports the `\033[<count>L` insertion, it should work as follows:

```
int main() {
    const int up_lines = 3;
    const int new_lines = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < new_lines; ++i) {
        // make space for existing lines to move down
        putchar('\n');
    }
    // move up and insert the new (empty lines)
    printf("\033[%dA\033[%dL", up_lines + new_lines, new_lines);

    for (int i = 0; i < new_lines; ++i) {
        printf("A%d\n", i);
    }

    // move back down below original lines
    printf("\033[%dB", up_lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically you first make room for the original lines to move down by outputting a number of newlines equal or greater to the number of lines you mean to insert (this step becomes relevant when the terminal position is so near the bottom that the old lines would move off screen). Then you move up to the insertion position (which has now moved by the number of newlines you printed) and insert the number of lines with `\033[<count>L`.

edit: Obviously you can repeat this as many times as you like, i.e., you don't have to know in advance how many lines you will insert and where, as long as you move back down to the last line after every batch of inserts. For example, you could insert one line at a time by always printing just one newline at the bottom, then moving up to the insertion position (remembering to account for the one line you just added in between), inserting the line there, and moving back down to the bottom.

Comment: It works in this example, however I don't know how many lines will be inserted. I want to print some output at the end, so I have to get the cursor up after printing these special lines. I don't want to overwrite other lines, it would be just a nice feature. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @Icebear You don't have to know how many lines will be inserted: you can use this same technique to insert any number of lines at a time in any position as many times as you like. For example, to insert one line at a time, print one newline, move up to the position, insert the line, move back down, repeat as many times as you want.

Comment: @Icebear Alternatively, instead of dynamically printing the empty lines, obtain the height of the terminal and fill one screen in the beginning, then move up to the top and operate within that space.

Comment: It is part of an embedded project. I want to print some lines generated by different threads independently from each other. Thread A has no way to find out how much Thread B has printed. I thought there might be something like an insertion mode.

Comment: @Icebear You don't need to find out how much another thread has printed, just how many positions up you want to move from the current position. Move up by that much, insert, move down by the same amount. Or if you are thinking that each thread has an independent cursor where they can just insert without moving up, that was never going to work since the terminal is a shared resource… (Not to mention it would be an entirely different question, e.g., "how to maintain independent cursor positions for multiple threads on the same terminal".)

Comment: @Icebear Meanwhile "thread A has no way to find out how much thread B has printed" is not true: you should mutex access to the terminal anyways, so if only one thread holds the terminal at a given time, they can also hold a shared variable that tracks the number of lines or cursor position or whatever.

Comment: The problem, I posted here is now solved. I have my embedded problem nearly solved. I use a RTOS that protects printf automatically.